# Сделать видео из браузера поверх RDP

Tags: поиск-программ

В общем, хочу, что бы когда я запускаю RDP во весь экран, то мог как-то сделать так, чтобы мой браузер запущенный на моем ПК был поверх RDP.

Т.е что-то типа картинка в картинке.

Есть ли какой-нибудь софт для этого или это как-то можно сделать средствами винды?

Comment: 1) не запускать во весь экран 2) второй монитор.
Зачем его делать во весь экран если в таком случае, все равно браузер часть закроет?

Comment: @teran, У меня 2 монитора, но РДП на 1 мониторе не удобно=( А так хотелось бы браузер с видосиком в уголке видеть.

Comment: в фаирфоксе на видосах с весны еще появилась кнопка, которая видосы поверх окон открывает в отдельным слоем. работает и поверх рдп

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение в Chrome:

2 раза нажимаем по видео правой кнопкой и в меню выбираем "Картинка в картинке"

Comment: @andreymal я чуть подправил сам вопрос